# Using searchController to filter tableView, but the tableView isn't updating

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` that is displaying the titles of Tags I created.  When I first navigate to the `UITableViewController`, it displays the `Array` of Tags just fine, but when I use the `UISearchController` to filter through Tags, the `Array` I created to store the filtered results updates and holds the correct data, but the `TableView` doesn't change.  here are the two functions that are most likely causing the problem, but just in case, I will have the entire class (not long) down below.
numberOfRowsInSection:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(searchController.searchBar.text != "") {
        return filteredTags.count
    }
    return Tags.count
}
```

cellForRowAt:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tagcell", for: indexPath) as! TagCell

    var text = ""
    if (searchController.searchBar.text != ""){
        text = filteredTags[indexPath.row].title
    } else {
        text = Tags[indexPath.row].title
    }

    cell.cellLabel.text = text
    return cell
}
```

Whole Class:

```
class TagCell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var cellLabel: UILabel!
}

class TagTableVC: UITableViewController{

    //Table Content

    var Tags: [Tag] = [globTS.animals, globTS.civilrights, globTS.guncontrol, globTS.gunrights, globTS.LGBTQ, globTS.prochoice, globTS.prolife]
    var filteredTags = [Tag]()

    //Searchbar Initialization
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    //Required Functions
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(searchController.searchBar.text != "") {
            return filteredTags.count
        }
        return Tags.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tagcell", for: indexPath) as! TagCell

        var text = ""
        if (searchController.searchBar.text != ""){
            text = filteredTags[indexPath.row].title
        } else {
            text = Tags[indexPath.row].title
        }

        cell.cellLabel.text = text
        return cell
    }

    //Filters Tags array into Filtered array based on search query
    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All"){
        filteredTags = Tags.filter{ $0.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())}
    }
}

extension TagTableVC: UISearchResultsUpdating {

    //calls the filter function everytime the searchbar is activated
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you reloadData() ?

Comment: reloadData isn't a function.  Do you mean I have to manually recall `numberOfRows` and `cellForRowAt` every time I change the data?

Comment: yes, I mean that tableView.reloadData()

Comment: You shouldn't call this table view data source methods. For this purpose UITableView has method reloadData()

Comment: My bad, I was calling reloadData on `self` not `self.tableView`.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reevaluating the filteredTags, you should call reloadData on your tableview

```
    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All"){
        filteredTags = Tags.filter{ $0.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())}
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: To anybody looking here in the future, make sure to call `reloadData()` on `self.tableView`, as opposed to just calling it on `self`, if you are in a `UITableViewController`.  It took me about 10 minutes to realize my mistake.